# How to prevent downloading or copying of a notebook?

Tags: publishing

When publishing a notebook to cloud using <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Publish to Cloud...</kbd> the published notebook is accessible and downloadable to desktop or copyable to edit online. Is there a way to prevent the user from downloading or creating their own copy but just view it in published mode in browser?

---

I tried to get the cloud object handle:

```
object=CloudObject[url];
```

Then I tried to look at the current permissions:

```
Options[object,Permissions]
```

> {Permissions -> {"Owner" -> {"Read", "Write", "Execute"}, PermissionsKey["mypassword"] -> {"Read", "Write", "Interact"}}}

When publishing the notebook I did set a password which can be seen here in `PermissionKey` and by default it is giving permission to "Read", "Write", "Interact". I tried to limit this permission to interact only using:

```
SetPermissions[object,{Permissions->{"Owner"->{"Read","Write","Execute"},PermissionsKey["mypassword"]->{"Interact"}}}]
```

But it fails with the following error:

> SetPermissions::invusr: Invalid user or permissions group Permissions.

How do I change this permission?

---

I found a way to workaround without relying on gui, I can create a new publish using the specific permissions on the notebook object using:

```
CloudPublish[notebookObject,url,Permissions->{
    "Owner"->{"Read","Write","Execute"},
    PermissionsKey["mypassword"]->{"Read"}
}]
```

But I can't find the Permission specification to get the wolfram cloud to stop the downloading or creating a copy of the notebook.

If I set it to "Read" only it is still possible to make a copy online in wolfram cloud. If I set it to "Interact" only then notebook is not viewable anymore.

So the question remains what `Permissions` specification would get me the desired result?